# Custom SharePoint Form that displays data from another List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint task list. Each task in the task list is for a Client, and there is a drop-down on the task entry form to select the client. The drop down is populated from a Clients list.

Each client has a tier. Tier is a field in the Client list.

What I want to do, is when a Client is selected in a New/Edit/View form from within sharepoint, I want the Tier to display.

I've created a Custom List Form in SharePoint designer, added a row to the form for the tier, but can't figure out how to populate the tier. I don't want it to be a form field, just to display for FYI purposes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this. There is a community-driven [jQuery Library for SharePoint](http://spservices.codeplex.com/). The [SPCascadeDropdowns function](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[PowerForms](http://www.bpc.gr/default.aspx?page=products-and-solutions/sharepoint/bpc-power-forms/en) supports external calls to SP lists or web services and displaying data in your form. It should do what you need.